# how to read a file created in rails using javascript within new.html.erb

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have this method in rails where i am creating external events.json file.

```
 def new
        @event=Event.new
        @users=User.all
        @events=@user.events
        tempJson = @events.to_json.html_safe
        aFile = File.new("events.json", "r+")
        aFile.syswrite(tempJson)
    end
```

now events.json file is created in my app directory.
In my new.html.erb, how to access this file via javascript and set it to a variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $.getJSON("events.json", function(json) {
        debugger;
         console.log(json);
       });      
    </script>
```

I tried this.. and i get this error message when i inspect,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/users/14/events/events.json
```

Comment: Why don't you render it as json from the method?

Comment: What is the actual path to where the file is stored? i.e which directory is it in?

Comment: @user2085143 the events.json file is generated and stored inside same application directory, where app, bin, etc directories are present [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2BZFbohNopKT1FIOTlpNi1hVEE)

Comment: I think your path might be a bit off hence why you're getting a 404. Have you tried '/events.json' in the get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the file to public/ directory. You can achieve this by doing:

```
File.new(Rails.public_path + 'events.json', 'w+')
```

Then, you can access the file in your view doing:

```
$.getJSON("/events.json")
```

But i think that the best way to achieve this is by having an EventsController with and index action that responds in json.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @events}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you. i came to know that browser searches for events.json file in public directory. now it works fine. :)

Comment: Better way to obtain public directory is like in @jrbedard answer with `Rails.public_path`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

First: Are you sure that the file is written? Because you use `File.new("events.json", "r+")` which I think means `read` you need `w+` for `write`

Second: Is the `location = "users/14/events/events.json"`

Use in both cases `Rails.public_path + path + /file`